# Good way to update automation skills with experience in selenium+c#

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#

I want to update my automation skills with experience in selenium+c# working as an Automation QA.

I am particularly interested in courses in the London area or online courses I can take to remain up to date with the latest automation knowledge and improve my career.

Answer (score 1):

> Automation is just tip of an iceberg called language.

Forget Automation intially and focus just on standard basic code exercises which can be practiced in any language of your choice like string reverse etc.

Atleast be proficient to use all the string, number and array in built functions up to level that if a small programming problem is given to you , you may readily able to code using library functions in a simplified way.

To update on automation and testing in general I would recommend an excellent online testing community called [ministry of testing.](https://www.ministryoftesting.com)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for places to start learning... it depends on what you have already learned.  What are you looking for?  I'd highly recommend you first start with your understanding of writing code and object oriented programming.

If you already have some skills in development I would recommend using pluralsight.com.  There are others such as toolsqa.com that has some good info.